# Get item from ConcurrentBag c#

Tags: c#

I have a function how return for me ConcurrentBag this ConcurrentBag contains ip and his port.
the first step he get the value of ip and his port from file txt.
tow he add this value to the ConcurrentBag.
tree he return a ConcurrentBag that containd ip and his port,

this is my function loadsocks :

```
public static ConcurrentBag<ServerSocks> loadSocks()
        {
            var result = new ConcurrentBag<ServerSocks>();
            string fileSocks = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "socks-list.txt"));
            var input = File.ReadAllText(fileSocks);
            var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
            foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
            {
                string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string port = match.Groups[2].Value;
                if (result.Any(x => x.IpAddress.Trim() == ip.Trim()))
                    continue; 
                result.Add(new ServerSocks { IpAddress = ip, Port = Convert.ToInt32(port) });

            }
            return result;
        }
```

the problem for me is into method main i want for each loop to give me a new ip and his port and i want to affect them to the properties oServer.SocksProxyServer and oServer.SocksProxyPort.

this is the code in the main method:

```
ConcurrentBag<ServerSocks> list = loadSocks();
            var oServer = new SmtpServer("");


            for (int i = 0; i < nRcpt; i++)
            {
                 while (!list.IsEmpty)
            {
                ServerSocks ipAndPort;
                if (!list.TryTake(out ipAndPort)) continue;
                try
                {
                    //code here to send message using below IP and Port
                    oServer.SocksProxyServer = ipAndPort.IpAddress;
                    oServer.SocksProxyPort = ipAndPort.Port;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

                arMail[i] = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
                arSmtp[i] = new SmtpClient();
                SmtpMail oMail = arMail[i];
                oMail.From = "";
                //oMail.DKCertificate
                oMail.Sender = "";
                oMail.Subject = "";
                oMail.TextBody = "";
                oMail.AutoTextBody = false;
                try
                {
                    string fileHtml = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "lettercmb.html"));
                    oMail.ImportHtmlBody(fileHtml, ImportHtmlBodyOptions.NoOptions);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                SmtpClient oSmtp = arSmtp[i];
                Console.WriteLine(oServer.SocksProxyServer);
                Console.ReadLine();
                arResult[i] = oSmtp.BeginSendMail(oServer, oMail, null, null);

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start to send email to {0} ...",
                                 arRcpt[i]));



            }
```

in my file txt i have 2 ip 134.34.54.154:17815
173.33.54.157:17815

he USE me always 134.34.54.154 , i dont know how is the problem in my code ,
what i want i want if the first message send the seconnd message must use the seconde ip what i should do ?

thanks

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: @JeffC i have edit my code can you tell if is good or no thnks??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is currently coded, your `oServer.SocksProxyServer = ipAndPort.IpAddress; oServer.SocksProxyPort = ipAndPort.Port;` are always going to be assigned the first value in the socks-list.txt file. You fill up the bag correctly and you take the ip's out of the bag one by one and assign them to the SocksProxyServer property but it keeps overwriting before you get to your send mail code.

I think you want to do something like:

```
ConcurrentBag<ServerSocks> list = loadSocks();
var oServer = new SmtpServer("");

for (int i = 0; i < nRcpt; i++)
{
    while (!list.IsEmpty)
    {
        try
        {   
            //code here to send message using below IP and Port
            oServer.SocksProxyServer = list[i%list.count].IpAddress;
            oServer.SocksProxyPort = list[i%list.count].Port;

            arMail[i] = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
            arSmtp[i] = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpMail oMail = arMail[i];
            oMail.From = "";
            //oMail.DKCertificate
            oMail.Sender = "";
            oMail.Subject = "";
            oMail.TextBody = "";
            oMail.AutoTextBody = false;
            try
            {
                string fileHtml = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "lettercmb.html"));
                oMail.ImportHtmlBody(fileHtml, ImportHtmlBodyOptions.NoOptions);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            SmtpClient oSmtp = arSmtp[i];
            Console.WriteLine(oServer.SocksProxyServer);
            Console.ReadLine();
            arResult[i] = oSmtp.BeginSendMail(oServer, oMail, null, null);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Start to send email to {0} ...",
                         arRcpt[i]));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        } 
        }        
    }
```

Edit: I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish here. The second time through the For loop the list will be empty because it removes the ip from the bag. Changing to a foreach will allow these ips to stay in the bag for the next time through the for loop. In this case a ConcurrentBag isn't really necessary.

Comment: i do like this but the problem he send one email twice by tow ip and they stop, he not continue to send other email

Comment: she work bro , but one email send twice, i want that email will be sent one time not twice

Comment: That will happen the way it is coded now. Are you trying to use the socks list to provide multiple proxies if one were to fail? If so you need to add a test case to break out of the foreach if the first proxy server connection was successful. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: do you have a team viewr

Comment: i can watch you what i want exactly

Comment: 300 583 829      6v82fn